# XML Write Getting Steadily Slower

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I think I was over complicating this before.

Writing the contents of several lists to an XML file. Writing one result takes a millisecond but 100 results take almost a good minute which doesn't make sense. I added a counter and each write is getting steadily slower than the last one.

I can't find the bottleneck in this. I don't understand what's slowing it down and I'm about a hairs breath away from just writing the data into notepad myself manually.

I've tried:

*Not checking for Temp.xml existing to set the tree/root and it didn't make a difference.

*Using the same list and not multiple ones just in case that was causing something strange.

*I thought it might of just been my system so I stuck it on a 40 core crazy level of SSD server and it has the same results.

The code:

```
def filewriter():
    while 1:
            time.sleep(10)
            if OnlyOneXMLWriteCheck == 1:
                WriteThatThread = Thread(target = FileWrite)
                WriteThatThread.start()
                WriteThatThread.join()

def FileWrite():
    try:
        if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
            os.remove("Temp.xml")

        EventDumpCounter = 0

        for Eventes in EventTags:
            try:

                if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
                    tree = ET.parse("Temp.xml")
                    root = tree.getroot()
                if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == False:
                    root = ET.Element("Refunds")
                    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

                if float(EventCost[EventDumpCounter]) > float(Price[EventDumpCounter]):

                    if "Horse" in EventTags[EventDumpCounter]:
                        Eventes = ET.SubElement(root, "Event", type = EventTags[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventTime").text = str(EventTimes[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventName").text = str(EventName[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventLoc").text = str(EventLoc[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventSpace").text = str(EventSpace[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventCost").text = str(EventCost[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventPrice").text = str(EventPrice[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventParking").text = str(EventParking[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventDist").text = str(EventDist[EventDumpCounter])
                        tree.write("Temp.xml")

                EventDumpCounter +=1

            except:
                print "Problem writing XML"

    #except:
    except WindowsError, e:
        print "Problem creating XML 2"
        #e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print e

KeepWritingFiles = Thread(target = filewriter)
KeepWritingFiles.start()
```

/Update:

After comments below it was suggested that parsing the XML every time was slowing things down. I was doing this so it could start a new XML or append to an existing one but I changed to this:

```
   if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
            if OnlyParseOnce == 0:
                print "opening file"
                OnlyParseOnce = 1
                tree = ET.parse("Temp.xml")
                root = tree.getroot()
        if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == False:
            root = ET.Element("Events")
            tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
```

"opening file" only displays once which would mean it's not constantly parsing the file and it's still slow. I wonder if "os.path.exists" is the bottleneck.

If I manually set it

```
 root = ET.Element("Refunds")
  tree = ET.ElementTree("Events")
```

It flies through the same amount of data in a second. No time at all. But that way it's not appending to an existing file it's constantly rewriting. So it might be the os.path.exists or maybe it's just because I'm writing one result instead of creating a larger file.

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess and say that the issue here is with the threading rather than the xml. Is there a reason for the `sleep` call?

Comment: If we forget the threading and I allow it to run just once I get the same result. Straight appending it as a text file runs a *lot* faster. As in the kind of speed I'd normally expect but there seems to be a problem retaining the structure.

Comment: Is the program successively appending to a single XML file? I could imagine that if this file starts getting very large, the time it takes to parse it is going to increase. In other words, it may be that the line `tree = ET.parse("Temp.xml")` keeps taking longer and longer to execute. Try timing how long it takes for just that line to execute.

Comment: If I remove that part and just useroot = ET.Element("Refunds") tree = ET.ElementTree(root) it flies through in no time. That looks promising. I don't know how to go about writing to a new or existing file with the right tags without using that but at least that's the bottleneck narrowed down. Thanks for taking the time I hope you have a fricking awesome day/evening/night.

Comment: You keep reparsing the document on every iteration so its going to get slower and slower as the file grows. So don't do that. Don't reload the document or write it per iteration.

Comment: Oh wait... Using that writes only one tree in of course (I'm sure there's a way around that) it might just be faster because I'm only writing one. Shouldn't jump to that conclusion. I'll figure out how to time that part individually.

Comment: I had it loading the file so it would be able to start a new file or append data onto an existing one. I don't really know another way of handling this but I'm assuming I'll find a way.

Comment: Oh a check so it only does it once... That should do the trick.

Comment: No dice. Made (and confirmed) a check so it's only parsing the xml once and it's still slow as sin. I'll update the question but I don't think that's the bottleneck.

Comment: Have you tried only *writing* the XML once as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code writes the document at the end of each loop with `tree.write("Temp.xml")` and then reads and parses it again with `tree = ET.parse("Temp.xml")`. This is completely pointless because `tree` is already in memory and doesn't need to be rebuilt. As the document grows, the cost of writing and reading goes up and performance goes down. Just use the in-memory `tree` object and delay writing until the loop completes.

```
def FileWrite():
    try:
        if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
            os.remove("Temp.xml")
        root = ET.Element("Refunds")
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

        EventDumpCounter = 0

        for Eventes in EventTags:
            try:
                if float(EventCost[EventDumpCounter]) > float(Price[EventDumpCounter]):
                    if "Horse" in EventTags[EventDumpCounter]:
                        Eventes = ET.SubElement(root, "Event", type = EventTags[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventTime").text = str(EventTimes[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventName").text = str(EventName[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventLoc").text = str(EventLoc[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventSpace").text = str(EventSpace[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventCost").text = str(EventCost[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventPrice").text = str(EventPrice[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventParking").text = str(EventParking[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventDist").text = str(EventDist[EventDumpCounter])
                EventDumpCounter +=1

            except: # bad idea, you just supressed debug info
                # potential problem = since you supress the error and continue
                # processing but EventDumpCounter never advanced, you could
                # get stuck in an infinite error loop.
                print "Problem writing XML"

        tree.write("Temp.xml")

    #except:
    except WindowsError, e:
        print "Problem creating XML 2"
        #e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print e
```